# dojo select field displayed value

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I use the dijit.form.select with the grid editor like this:

```
editor({    
    label: 'status',
    field: 'status_name',
    editorArgs: {
        style: "width:75px;",
        options: task_status
    },
    className: 'style8'
}, Select, "dblclick"),
```

when I open the select field and choose an option from the list, this returns the 'value' of selected option not the name of it.
how to get the value instead of the value?

Comment: what do you men by name?

Comment: I mean the displayed value of the option not it's value

Answer (score 0):

Check the objects in your options list.
Each object should have a label and value property. The label is what will be displayed when selected.